# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library?

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm running cocos2d-x on eclipse and I always get that message.

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\cocos2dx\platform\android\java\bin\libcocos2dx.jar'

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your cocos2d-x library is not installed properly. Try reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the reply. But what exactly should i reinstall? the whole lib or just certain things?

Comment: I actually don't know much about cocos2e-x, so I'd recommend reinstalling everything. You may need to reinstall the entire Android SDK, but I'd first start with this library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `cocos2dx android library project` from `cocos2dx/platform/android/java` directory to your workspace and build it.

Comment: Thanksfor your reply, but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Obviously if you have to added this lib project to your game project then you need to remove library proejct and then clean build and add it again  to your project.

Answer (score 0):

- Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code -> Choose `project`. This will import your cocos2dx project into eclipse
- Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code -> Choose `project/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java`. This will import `libcocos2dx` for your project into eclipse
- Right click `project` -> Properties -> Android -> Library panel make sure `libcocos2dx` has been added here. This will include the `libcocos2dx.jar` as a dependency for the project and can be checked in Java Build Path -> Android Dependencies
- Eclipse -> Project -> Clean -> Clean All Projects
- Eclipse -> Project -> Build All. This will build `project` and it's `libcocos2dx.jar` dependency.
- Then on the command line run `cocos run -p android` or `cocos run -p android -m release` to build and run it on connected android device.

Comment: Did any of the solutions outlined fix your issue?